# "I saw him be walking" - is it grammatically correct?

Tags: verbs, emphasis

My teacher told me that this sentence is correct:
"I saw him be walking"

Is it grammatically ok?

Comment: Your teacher is **wrong**. It should be "I saw him walking."

Comment: Time to get.a better teacher. The sentence quoted is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong, the correct one is `I saw him walking`.

There is a slight difference between `I saw him walking` and `I saw him walk` though.

You can [read](https://www.quora.com/Which-is-correct-I-saw-him-walk-into-his-office-just-now-or-I-saw-him-walking-into-his-office-just-now) this one for the difference.

Comment: Thank you but could you tell me why "I saw him be walking" is not right? I see the difference between "walk" and "walking" in this sence. But  "I saw him walking" and "I saw him be walking" seem to mean the same to me. Please help me :)

Comment: It is a tricky problem, because sometimes you do seem to use the bare infinitive, like "I saw him **eat fish**."  But that's not how you express the object of a sentence performing a progressive action; you just say "object verb-ing."